# More efficient way of removing line indices?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After profiling my current script I've found that nearly 100% of the run time (and I'm not surprised) comes from the following function:

```
def rem_asc_by_pos(xmlFile, fileOut,removeIndices):
fileIn = xmlFile.replace('.xml', '.asc')
with open(fileIn, 'r') as fin:
    with open(fileOut, 'w') as fout:
        #remove indices from each line and write to new file
        if len(removeIndices) > 0:
            for line in fin:
                lineList = list(line)
                checkLine = ''
                newLine = []
                for ind,char in enumerate(lineList):
                    if ind not in removeIndices:
                        newLine.append(char)
                lineOut = ''.join(newLine)
                fout.write(lineOut)
```

The files themselves can have anywhere from a 15 thousand lines to 2.5 million at the most, each line is usually from 300-600 characters.

I was thinking that the write operation may be causing an increase in run-time so I could write multiple lines at a time but wouldn't know a good way to determine when it should write the lines (so as to not run out of memory).

Is there anything obvious that I might be able to change to decrease the overall run-time? To go through all the files currently it takes about 20 hours and any decrease from that is appreciated!

edit: Adding an example of input and expected output!

Input:
I have a bunch of data files that look similar to this:

```
511111 12  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   .750000
511112 12  1.000000   .666667   .500000   .555556
```

The removeIndicies list contains the indicies to remove from each line, for this example we want to remove the first three and indicies 19-28.

Expected output:

```
111 12  1.000000  1.000000   .750000
112 12  1.000000   .500000   .555556
```

Comment: Can you explain what this function is supposed to do? Can you give examples of the input and output?

Comment: I've added an example of the input file lines and the expected output.

Comment: What was wrong with `cut`? I mean, couldn't you just run `cut -c 4-18,29- FILE`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the XML file has the indices of the variablesToRemove. I'll reduce the code example so that it is more relevant. I can't find any reference to 'cut' in the pydocs.

Comment: [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) is a standard Unix utility for carrying out this kind of task. It will be much faster than doing it in Python. (You might still want to use Python to build the `cut` command line.)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I'm limited to Windows as my current platform but I'll see if I can find a solution along these lines.

Comment: Are the files all self-consisten, or do they have header data? If they are homogenous you could split them into a comfortable size for read-all-write-all processing (appending as necessary) to cut down on the IO thrashing

Comment: I think the answers to the question [_Efficient way of parsing fixed width files in Python_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4915359/355230) might be helpful. Specifically, **Update 2** in my own answer which supports negative widths to represent ignored "padding" fields.

Comment: I agree with you, that is very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Test case

You can't fix what you don't measure. So let's make a test case containing a million lines similar to the example input in your question:

```
>>> with open('in.txt', 'w') as f:
...     for _ in range(10**6):
...         _ = f.write('511111 12  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   .750000\n')
```

How long does your code take?

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> indices = list(range(3)) + list(range(18, 29))
>>> timeit(lambda:rem_asc_by_pos('in.txt', 'out.txt', indices), number=1)
32.99110442500023
```

#### 2. Rewrite

Here's a quick rewrite to simplify your code:

1. Follow the Python style guide ([PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).
2. Write a docstring explaining what the code does.
3. Pick a better name for the function.
4. Combine the two `with` clauses into one to keep the indentation sensible.
5. No need to pass mode `'r'` to `open`: that's the default.

And some changes to speed it up:

1. Turn the list of removed indices into a `set`, so that we can look up indices in constant time.
2. There's no need to split `line` into a list: you can iterate over a string just as easily.
3. Drop the `checkLine` and `newList` and `lineOut` intermediate variables.
4. Cache `fout.write` in a local variable to avoid having to look it up for every line.

```py
def remove_indices(file_in, file_out, indices):
    """Copy file_in to file_out, removing the given indices."""
    index_set = set(indices)
    with open(file_in) as fin, open(file_out, 'w') as fout:
        write = fout.write
        for line in fin:
            write(''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(line) if i not in index_set))
```

This is about twice as fast (in my test case):

```
>>> timeit(lambda:remove_indices('in.txt', 'out.txt', indices), number=1)
17.147783935997722
```

#### 3. Use slices instead of indices

The next improvement is to represent the parts of the line to be *kept* (rather than the parts to be *removed*) in the form of Python [`slice`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) objects. A slice object represents a range of indices in the same form as an array slice, that is, as *start* and *stop* indices together with a *step*.

So if you are going to *remove* indices 0–2 and 18–28, then you are going to *keep* indices 3–17 and 29–. In slice notation that would be:

```
>>> slices = [slice(3, 18), slice(29, None)]
```

Note that the *stop* for the first slice is 18, because ranges of integers in Python are always *exclusive* at the top.

Here's a version of your function that takes slices to keep instead of indices to remove:

```
def keep_slices(file_in, file_out, slices):
    """Copy file_in to file_out, keeping the given slices."""
    with open(file_in) as fin, open(file_out, 'w') as fout:
        write = fout.write
        for line in fin:
            for s in slices:
                write(line[s])
```

This is substantially faster:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:keep_slices('in.txt', 'out.txt', slices), number=1)
1.877711878001719
```

That's about an 18 times speedup (on this test case; it might be different on other test cases). Is that good enough for you? It ought to reduce your 20 hour runtime to an hour or so.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the advice, it is very much appreciated! I will certainly work on my style and documentation. I can see a lot of useful methods that I hope to carry on through with my work! Again thank you!